# Pi Spigot algorithm - Incorrect digit in the midst of correct digits- Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pi

I'm unable to find help on this specific problem.
When computing upwards of 500 digits, I get one decimal wrong in the midst of correct digits. I have already accommodated the +1 carry for large remainders.
If you run the code for 500 as below you get Pi as: "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903**51**001133053054882046652138414695194151160943305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912"

Notice in bold there is 51 , that should be a 6. I have no idea what is causing that carry over error. Im sorry for the shit code. I'm burned out trying to understand the wrong decimal.

```
def pispig(n):
    n = int(round(4*n))
    pistr = []
    multq = 0
    asum = 0
    tsum = []
    carover = 0
    counter = 1
    remainders = []
    a = [x for x in range(n)]
    b = [(2*(x))+1 for x in range(n)]
    init = [2 for x in range(1,n+1)]
    x10 = [10*x for x in init]
    while True:
        try:
            for B,y,A in zip(reversed(b), reversed(x10), reversed(a)):
                asum = carover+y
                remainders.insert(0,asum%B)
                tsum.insert(0, asum)
                multq = asum//B
                carover = multq*A
            if tsum[0] >= 100:
                pistr[-1] += 1
                pistr.append(tsum[0]%100)
            else:
                pistr.append(tsum[0]//10)
            remainders[0] = tsum[0]%10
            x10 = [10*x for x in list(remainders)]
            carover = 0
            remainders = []
            tsum = []
            asum = 0
            if len(pistr) > n//4:
                break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print(''.join(pistr))
            sys.exit(0)
    print('3.'+''.join(str(x) for x in pistr[1:]))

pispig(500)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that:
Despite catching sums over 100 for carry error, I was not catching additions double digit additions to the string, like a 10, that should have been carried. By adding: """

```
    if tsum[0] >= 100:
        pilist[-1] += 1
        pilist.append(0)
        if pilist[-2] == 10:
            pilist[-3] += 1
            pilist[-2] = pilist[-2] % 10
```

"""

```
def pispig(n):
    e = n
    n = 4*n
    """Need around 4 times as many terms for n digits"""
    pilist, remainders, tsum = [],[], []
    multq, asum, carover, counter = 0, 0, 0, 1
    """Initialize numerators of mixed base"""
    a = [x for x in range(n)]
    """Initialize denominators of mixed base"""
    b = [(2*(x))+1 for x in range(n)]
    """Initialize Pi in mixed base"""
    init = [2 for x in range(1,n+1)]
    """Multiply by 10**x for decimal conversion"""
    x10 = [(10**e)*x for x in init]
    while True:
        try:
            for A, B, R in zip(reversed(a), reversed(b), reversed(x10)):
                asum = carover+R
                remainders.insert(0,asum%B)
                tsum.insert(0, asum)
                multq = asum//B
                carover = multq*A
            if tsum[0] >= (10**(e+1)):
                pilist[-1] += 1
                pilist.append((tsum[0]%(10**(e+1)))//(10))
                if pilist[-2] >= (10**e):
                    pilist[-3] += 1
                    pilist[-2] = pilist[-2] % (10**e)
            else:
                pilist.append(tsum[0]//(10))
            counter += 1
            print('***'+str(counter)+'***', end='\r')
            remainders[0] = tsum[0]%(10**e)
            x10 = [10*x for x in list(remainders)]
            carover = 0
            remainders = []
            tsum = []
            asum = 0
            if len(str('3.'+''.join(str(x) for x in pilist[1:]))) > n//4:
                break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('3.'+''.join(str(x) for x in pilist[1:]))
            sys.exit(0)
    print('3.'+''.join(str(x) for x in pilist[1:]))
```